# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hey I am trying to add a rails 4.2 project to heroku. However i keep coming up with this error

This is the log trace

```
Anish-laptop:wise-owl anish.patel$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake         assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "*, :": expected pseudoclass or        pseudoelement, was " after, :before"
(sass):152
/Users/anish.patel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.14/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1162:in `expected'
/Users/anish.patel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.14/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1098:in `expected'
/Users/anish.patel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.14/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1093:in `tok!'
/Users/anish.patel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.14/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:277:in `pseudo'
/Users/anish.patel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.14/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:154:in `simple_selector_sequen
```

**Production.rb**

```
'Rails.application.configure do
 config.cache_classes = true
 config.eager_load = true
 config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
 config.serve_static_files = true
 config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
 config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
 config.assets.compile = true
 config.assets.digest = true
 config.log_level = :info
 config.i18n.fallbacks = true
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
 config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
 end'
```

When it was working, my images were not loading. If you need more information please let me know as I'm not sure which files are relevant to link.

Comment: Never mind i solved it it was a problem with my gem files i just disabled the sass passer 
        `# Use SCSS for stylesheets
         group :assets do
 #gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
        end`